# Is there a way to determine a constant error during the compilation time?

Tags: java, error-handling

When I take out a value from the Map in Java, sometimes I got an error at run-time. because the key String constant have some typo.
So, Is there any way to find out this typo at compile time?

Comment: Yes, don't use string constants. Consider [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead.

Comment: Use a constant to store your string, then there should be no no typo.